# Understanding Sum Property of determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $A=B+C$, where $B=\begin{bmatrix}a &b &c\\
  d& e& f\\
g &h& i\end{bmatrix}$ and $C=\begin{bmatrix}k &k &k\\
  0& 0& 0\\
0 &0& 0\end{bmatrix}$, then $|A|=|B|+|C|$. Since $|C|=0$, so, $|A|=|B|$.

But, if we consider the properties of determinants, then $\left| \begin{array}{c c c} a+k & b+k & c+k \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right|=\left| \begin{array}{c c c} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right|+\left| \begin{array}{c c c} k & k & k \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{array}\right|$. Thus, $|A|\ne|B|$.

What is wrong in the first method?

Comment: it is false that $|B+C| = |B| + |C|$. Where did you find this property?

Comment: The determinant is linear w.r.t matrix *multiplication*, **not** addition.

Comment: ok, thanks guys. If you could post this as an answer, that would be great. I would accept the answer. And I hope I be cut slack on the downvote, as I am specifically asking 'what's wrong in the first method'. Your explanation has helped me see my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false that $|B+C| = |B| + |C|$.

The true result, is that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants. In formulae,
$|BC| = |B|\cdot |C|$.